# Area of a triangle where the three vertices are randomly chosen on a circle; also $3D$ version.

Tags: geometry, statistics, geometric-probability

My teacher gave us an interesting problem today. Consider a circle of radius $1$, choose three points on that circle at random and make a triangle connecting the three. On average what will the area of the triangle be?

One kid eventually got it and he told him to do it with $4$ points on a sphere making a tetrahedron and to find the average volume.

This was in a homeroom class, where the students in the class had him the previous year in AP Calc, so I'm not sure what the tags should be or what math is used.

Comment: This problem is known as [Circle triangle picking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircleTrianglePicking.html) and the expecte area of triangle is $\frac{3}{2\pi}$. The 3d version is known as [Sphere tetrahedron picking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphereTetrahedronPicking.html) and the expected volume of tetrahedron is $\frac{4\pi}{105}$. In general, these sort of stuff should fall under the topic "geometric probability".

Comment: @achillehui Thank you!

Comment: @achillehui: Doesn't one encounter the same type of problem as in [Bertrand's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability))?

Comment: One quick simplification is that if you fix one point and choose the other two at random, the answer is the same because of symmetry.

Comment: @AlexM. Bertrand paradox talks about the difficulty in specifying this type of problem unambiguously, not the problems themselves.

Comment: Think minimum and maximum: $0$ and the equilateral triangle